# Oracle Direct path insert issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that is truncated and INSERTED (APPEND) loaded. While this load is in progress (150 mins), I have another query (of course another session) that uses and reads from this table. I see that the query that reads from this table is also delayed or waits for the similar time (150 mins).

Now my question is: when direct path load happens, session outside the actual session reads previous version but it still can read. In this case, table is truncated. What does it read? why does it wait?

Comment: Direct path insert doesn't block reads(unless there is `for update` clause in your query). It blocks "writes". So, there are probably something else you are not telling us.  Plus it seems odd to query a table, while long running direct path insert is in progress.

Comment: Truncate is non-transactional in Oracle (and immediately committed) so the other session will never see any data until the insert is finished. Why the wait happens is hard to tell though.

Answer (score 2):

There's a system view called **gv$session** listing all the sessions connected to the database. One column is **event**, which indicates what the session is waiting for (if anything). While the query is running, check the value of the event column for that session. That will tell you exactly what it is waiting on.